# Shift in the Entry text value each time the <KeyRealase> event take places

Tags: python, tkinter, events, keyboard-events, tkinter-entry

I created an Entry to select an xlsx file from keyboard or file browser.

If this one has an xlsx extension and that it exists in the file explorer so I color it in black, otherwise in red.

check_entries allows me to check the file each time a key is pressed when the Entry has focus.

```
self.entries['entry1'] = Entry(inputs_frame, width=90, state=DISABLED)

self.entries['entry1'].bind("<KeyRelease>", lambda event: self.check_entries(event, self.entries['entry1']))
```

```
def check_entries(self, event, entry):

    entry.config(text=event.widget.get())
    all_entry_compliant = True

    for key, entry in self.entries.items():
        entry_compliant = True
        if key != 'report_file_pathname_entry':
            if os.path.exists(entry['text']) == False:
                entry_compliant = False
                all_entry_compliant = False

        if os.path.splitext(entry['text'])[1] != '.xlsx':
            entry_compliant = False
            all_entry_compliant = False

        if entry_compliant:
            entry.configure(fg='black')
        else:
            entry.configure(fg='red')

    if all_entry_compliant:
        self.buttons['launch_btn'].configure(state=NORMAL)
    else:
        self.buttons['launch_btn'].configure(state=DISABLED)
```

I don't understand why this writes the text with an offset. I alose tried to use <Key>, <FocusOut> event and to filter pressed key with regular expression.

[After selected xlsx file from file browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FObp3.png)

[After erase the letter 'o'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7sOc.png)

[After rewrite the letter 'o'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzR8y.png)

[After press left arrow key without pressed 'o'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TfVK.png)

#(Edit) Adding of minimable reproducible example

```
import tkinter as tk

def check_entries(event, entry):
    entry.config(text=event.widget.get())

root = tk.Tk()
entries = {}
entries['entry1'] = tk.Entry(root, width=90)
entries['entry1'].pack()

entries['entry1'].bind("<KeyRelease>", lambda event: check_entries(event, entries['entry1']))
root.mainloop()
```

If you try this code, when you press any letter or spam arrow on your keyboard, entry's text will take his old value.

Comment: I don't see how we're supposed to make this code work. For one, you define `self.entries['entry1']` but pass in `self.entries['supplier_quotation_entry']`. Also, you call `event.get()` but an event object passed in via a binding doesn't have a `get` method so this line of code will throw an error. Also, you use `entry['text']` which doesn't return the string stored in the entry.

Comment: Indeed, I made a mistake in the post. I corrected your first 2 remarks which are not present in my local code. I replace `entry['text']`by `entry.get()`, but it's always the same. The problem is only on the first 2 lines of the function. When I comment out the for loop I still have the same problem so it has no impact on it.

Comment: `check_entries` also explicitly looks for the key 'report_file_pathname_entry' which it will never find in this code.

Comment: `entry.config(text=event.widget.get())` doesn't update the text of the widget, it is assigning the text in the widget as the `textvariable` option of the entry ('text' is shorthand for 'textvariable' in this context)

Comment: It would be best if you could post a single block of code which reproduces the problem, that we can immediately copy, paste, and run without modification. See [mcve] for more information.

Comment: I added a minimal reproducbile example. I dont understand how set entry's text if `text`= `textvariable` here :/

Comment: The entry widget has `insert` and `delete` methods for inserting and deleting text.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `entry.config(text=event.widget.get())`, you are *not* changing the text in the entry widget. The widget does not have a `text` attribute. When you use `text`, tkinter interprets that as an abbreviation for `textvariable`. So, you are just setting `textvariable` to the value in the widget.

If you want to modify the entry widget, you can use the `delete` method to delete the text, and `insert` to insert new data.

For example, to replace the contents of `entry` with the text "hello, world", you can do it like this:

```
entry.delete(0, "end")
entry.insert(0, "hello, world")
```

In your example you're attempting to replace the text with what is already there, so I'm not sure what you're actually wanting to replace it with. It seems pointless to delete and just re-insert the same text.